# Mouse controller doesn't work from terminal but works from PyCharm

Tags: python

I want to simulate a clic on my screen using python.

```
print(xmin)
print(ymin)
mouse = Controller()
mouse.position = (xmin, ymin)
time.sleep(1)
mouse.click(Button.left, 2)
```

This code works when I'm running process from PyCharm
But if I execute this code from terminal

```
python main.py
```

It doesn't work... I don't understand.
From Pycharm, my mouse moved to position x,y and click, and from terminal it doesn't move and click..
Code is running because in both case, it display prints.

Strange problem, someone understand?

Comment: Can you provide more information about the O.S., python version? Maybe you are running a different python version from PyCharm and your console. Have you tried executing from the console python3 main.py?

Comment: I m running sys.version and displayed 3.7.7, python -V from terminal = 3.7.7 et python3 -V from terminal = 3.7.7...
I'm on mac OS Catalina..

Comment: I'm pretty sure that controlling the mouse requires permission on a Mac - you have apparently granted that permission for PyCharm, but not for running your code from the terminal (I'm not really sure what you'd grant permission *to*, in that case).

Comment: I have already verified... I will investigate more, but I dont' know if it's the problem ..

Comment: Ok thanks a lot.. I have tried on other terminal and it open settings to authorize mouse control... And I accepted for previous terminal too and now it works.. Thanks a lot...